# Is there a way to find the digest of a docker image with a given tag on a specific date?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-api

I am trying to get the corresponding digest of a docker image with a given tag on a specific date (since the image under the tag might have been overwritten since then), such as getting the digest of the image alpine:latest on 17/12/2020. Is there a way to get this information using Dockerhub API or another source?